# Is it possible to change the map group while the server is running?

Tags: server-administration, counter-strike-global-offensive

I am in the process of configuring a Counterstrike: Global Offensive server and I was wondering if it is possible to change the active map group while the server is running, without having to restart the server process?

The map group is defined as part of launching the server process, and the server process in fact does not allow people to connect unless you have defined a map group (it gives players the loading screen where the map details and server mode information is usually displayed, but it never connects and eventually times out).

From what I can tell, map groups are defined in the gamemodes_server.txt file as follows;

```
"mapgroups"
{
    "mg_bomb"
    {
        "name"          "mg_bomb"
        "maps"
        {
            "de_dust"   ""
            "de_dust2"  ""
            "de_nuke"   ""
            "de_train"  ""
            "de_inferno"    ""
            "de_aztec"  ""
        }
    }

    "mg_hostages"
    {
        "name"          "mg_hostages"
        "maps"
        {
            "cs_italy"  ""
            "cs_office" ""
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I launch the game with `+mapgroup mg_bomb`, the call vote -> change map list only shows the maps from the map group 'mg_bomb' (ie: dust, dust 2, etc) but not the maps from mg_hostages. If I start the game with `+mapgroup mg_hostages` then I only see the maps from mg_hostages.

Is it possible to change the map group while the server is running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is 5 years too late, but...

Any startup commands that start with a `+` are actually cvars that can also be changed in the server console.

i.e. `mapgroup mg_hostages` in the server console should change to the mg_hostages map group for the end of map vote.

Comment: On a side note, I don't have a CS:GO server to test this on.

Answer (score -1):

I am sure that this does not strictly stop you from changing the map to one of your choice, it just simply does not auto-change to them and rotate through a different map group.

You should still be able to change to a map of your choice, as long as this is in the maps folder on your server, using the `map xx_xxx` command.

Comment: The question is not about changing map, it is about changing the active map group!

Comment: I understand that, however, you don't actually have an issue, you can be on any map group that you wish and change to any map that you have hosted on your server, regardless of the map group set.